# angular calendar component does not work

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

can someone help me about angular calendar problem as follow:

```
following is the plunker
```

'http://plnkr.co/edit/fChjjzknFOWmLcuUomeD?p=preview`

```
where "calendar.js" comes from
```

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar

```
and "fullcalendar.js","moment.min.js" and "fullcalendar.css" are from
```

http://fullcalendar.io/download/

I just want to display calendar and string "Hello world" at the moment

Answer (score 1):

In your Plunkr example, you named the app wrong in your index view.

```
 ng-app="plunker"
```

instead of

```
 ng-app="app"
```

Check this working Plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/11GUvB6CjnZxrk6dlEnk?p=preview

Always check your console for errors before worrying about calendars, etc.

Comment: Yes, you are right , thanks a lot :=) i make sometimes very stupid thing ~~